# Protractor:count() doesn't work outside promise loop

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

```
var notifications = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content']"));
notifications.count().then(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
});
 console.log(value);
```

How to print the Value outside the promise loop which needs to compare with another variable?
I need this 'value' to compare not in except statement.
Please guide me.

Comment: var notifications = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content1']"));
notifications.count().then(function (value1) {
    console.log(value1);
});


var notifications = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content2']"));
notifications.count().then(function (value2) {
    console.log(value2);
});
expect(value1).toBe(Value2);

Comment: How we can compare these value1 and value2?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example of asynchronous programming in JavaScript. You can refer [Protractor: what's the difference between ignoreSynchronization and async/await in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218642/protractor-whats-the-difference-between-ignoresynchronization-and-async-await/63241332#63241332) this answer to understand how execution happens

Now to answer your question, you can use async/ await instead of .then and store the value.

```
it('should get count', async () => {
  await browser.get("url of application");
  let count = await element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification- content']")).count();
  console.log(count);
});
```

Hope this will solve your answer

Edit:

```
it("test", () => {
    let count1, count2;
    browser.get("url of application");
    var notifications = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content']"));
    count1 = notifications.count();
    var notifications = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content']"));
    count2 = notifications.count();
    expect(count1).toBe(count2);
  });
```

Comment: I need to compare the values coming from 2 different promises.          

var notifications = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content1']"));
notifications.count().then(function (value1) {
    console.log(value1);
});


var notifications = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content2']"));
notifications.count().then(function (value2) {
    console.log(value2);
});

expect(value1).toBe(Value2); How to achive this?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, just one modification you can do. Instead of logging values, you can store them in variables and then compare them. I have edited my answer. it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. This is working. I have one doubt I want to get this Count1 value then apply any formula(like caluculate % value or multiply with 22/7) then how I can do that? Please guide me.

Comment: `count1 = notifications.count().then((value) => (value * 22) / 7);`
count1 will be the value you want.

If you find my answer helpful, please upvote and accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: If able to print count1 value now? console.log(count1); like this?

Comment: I am afraid you cant print value using `console.log` you can give it a try. If you want to print the values then you can adopt the async/ await approach instead of .then()

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use async/await in this scenario. However, if you have to use the approach you posted in your snippet you would do it like this.

```
var notifications1 = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content1']"));
var notifications2 = element.all(by.xpath("//div[@class='notification-content2']"));

notifications1.count().then(function (count1) {
  notifications2.count().then(function (count2) {
    expect(count1).toEqual(count2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out!

use **async/await** instead of promise chaining.
Writing code with promise chaining is a bit complex and not gives a flexible approach to write code.
https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await

```
let notifications;
let value;

async GetElementCount() {
   notifications = await element.all(by.xpath('//div[@class=\'notification-content\']'));
   return notifications.count();
}

value = await GetElementCount();
```

now you can print the Value outside and compare with another variable.

Comment: System is accepting after entering function keyword "async function GetElementCount()". After running it gives "Promise { <pending> }".     Please guide me what I missed  here.

Comment: await GetElementCount(); check this out